# C# Foreach list method static

Tags: c#

So I want to reference the string " line " in my foreach method within another function.

Example of code:

```
public static void Datas()
{
    foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(@"in.txt").Skip(0))
    {
        string[] data = line.Split(':');
        string email = data[0];
        string phone = data[1];
    }
}
```

Example of expectation:

```
public static void Info()
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

but unfortunately as expected " line " does not exist in the current context.

Comment: line only exists inside that foreach in data  ....

Comment: It´s hard to guess what you *actually* want to achieve by this. Basically you need to declare a variable on the class-level, not within the method, in order to use it everywhere in the class. But we don´t know your actual context. I doubt that making `line` a class-member is a good idea in your case. Better would be to have a list/array of your parsed data. However that´s just a guess.

Comment: You could pass line to info - but as you dont show where or when you want to use info.. we cant do anything

Comment: Which line? Shouldn't you just call the method from within the loop, passing current `line` as parameter?

Comment: @BugFinder I understand that line only exists within that foreach, I'm asking how I can make that static within my class.. so that it can be called within Info(), also lets say I trigger info(); within Data(), then i would like for info to output line

Comment: Well, what do you expect `line` to be when calling the method? The very first line? The second? The last? I guess what you *actually* want is an array/list of emails and phone-numbers, don´t you?

Comment: its not the word static you need.. you are confusing yourself - you want "line" to be a class level variable then if you dont want to pass it about.

Comment: `public static void Info(string line)` and then in your loop call `Info(line);`

Comment: How do those methods rely on each other? How and in particular *where* do you call them? Please show a bit more of your code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Edit: I formatted the code. Explanation: You should have the method Info take in a line parameter and then call Info inside Datas.

```
public static void Datas()
    {
        foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(@"in.txt").Skip(0))  
        { 
            string[] data = line.Split(':'); 
            string email = data[0]; 
            string phone = data[1];

            Info(line);
        } 
    }

    public static void Info(string line)
    { 
       Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
```

Comment: You could at least format your code a bit and explain what it does and how it solves the issue.

Comment: @HimBromBeere his answer worked regardless & I also understand what it does/how it solves the issue.. I should have really thought of that to be honest >.<